# Relocation in MPLAB IDE X

Tags: avr, bootloader, mplabx, avr-gcc, linker

I'm writing a bootloader for [ATXMEGA256A3U](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-8386-8-and-16-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATxmega64A3U-128A3U-192A3U-256A3U_datasheet.pdf). At page 14, Table 7.1 of the datasheet I know the bootloader address start at 0x20000.

Using AtmelStudio I set in the linker option the following relocation:

```
.text=0x20000
```

and my bootloader work fine.
Now in MPLAB IDE X, I tried to do the same inside Project properties > Avr GCC > avr-ld > MemorySettings > FLASH segment.

But the whole generated hex is empty (all 0xFF). I also tried to lower the start address, i.e. `.text=0x800` but it's the same.

To be sure, I inspected the generated command line and seems correct to me:

```
"libm";"libm" -Wl,--gc-sections  -Wl,-section-start=.text=0x20000
```

How to relocate the base address of my firmware to 0x20000?
By the way, the actual byte address is 0x40000.

Comment: I've tried to repeat what you are trying to do. Created a simple test project for this target. And after adding .text=0x20000 I can see this address in HEX file: :10020000... and lss generated disassemble shows ISR vectors start at 40000 (byte) location: Disassembly of section .text:
00040000 <__vectors>:

Comment: @NStorm interesting, so you're suggesting there's a problem in my setup? What version of MPLAB IDE X are you using?

Comment: Not sure why it's not working on your side. But I'm running latest versions. v5.35 and avr-gcc toolchain from Microchip (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.6.2_1759) 5.4.0. On Win10 x64.